# ¿Como eliminar los primeros registros de un excel en c#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

estoy intentando de cargar los datos de un excel a datagridview, y pues este es mi resultado de la carga.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi pregunta es como eliminaria esas Column1, Column2, Column3.. etc..
y que mi resultado quede de la forma en que product id, unidad de medida, clave, etc.
sean los nombres de las columnas del datagridview.

este es el excel.. original
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero su respuesta..
gracias..

---

Este es el codigo, cabe mencionar que no he hecho ninguna logica, solo he realizado la carga al grid.

```
private void btnExaminar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel WorkBooks|*xlsx|Excel WorkBooks 1997-2003|*xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                        IExcelDataReader reader;
                        if (ofd.FilterIndex == 1)
                        {
                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(fs);// leer archivos excel xlsx
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);// leer archivos excel xls

                        }
                        result = reader.AsDataSet(new ExcelDataSetConfiguration()
                        {
                            UseColumnDataType = true,
                            ConfigureDataTable = (tableReader) => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration()
                            {
                                UseHeaderRow = true
                            }
                        });//**
                           //  cbCarga.Items.Clear();
                          dgvExcel.DataSource = result.Tables[1];
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        if (!(ex is FileNotFoundException || ex is ArgumentException))
                        {
                            throw;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hola JuanL, por favor integra tu código

Comment: @ManuelMorales ya esta disponible el codigo, en este caso solo cargo los datos del excel al grid de esa forma como esta el codigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que creo que tienes es que tienes definido ya un header en tu `datagridview` entonces al momento de que insertas la demás información la deja ahí, `c#` tiene una propiedad llamada `ColumnHeaderVisible` colocala en `false`

Comment: y asi fue, me soluciono mi problema..